# Two submits one ajax one regular form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this form that i am trying to submit with ajax as well as the regular submit the regular submit is for creating a pdf and the ajax submit is for showing an html example for showing the preview which both work just fine if i use them both individually or use the create pdf before the preview submit but if sumbit for pdf after the preview submit it's not functional, nothing happens like regular submit button is disabled. My code is attached as folows, Do note both work fine just the regular post doesn't work if i use ajax submit first.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submitpdf').submit(function() {
        return true;
    });

    $('#submitpreview').click(function() {
        $('#form').submit(function(event) { // catch the form's submit event
            $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...

                data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
                type: $(this).attr('GET'), // GET or POST
                url: 'test.php', // the file to call
                success: function(response) { // on success..
                    $('#created').html(response); // update the DIV

                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is the HTMl of the form tag and the submit buttons:

```
<form action="dopdf.php" name="formular" id="form" method="GET" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="submit" id="submitpdf" value="Create PDF" name="print" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('act').value='0'" style="margin-left: 0;" />
<input id="submitpreview" type="submit" value="Preview!" name="preview" class="btn btn-primary submit-button" onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('act').value='0'" style="margin-left: 0;" />
      </form>
```

One other thing to note is that with ajax i want to submit to "test.php" and with regular submit i want to submit to "dopdf.php".

Comment: where is the div `created` ?

Comment: That's what `return false` does, it prevents the form from submitting ?

Comment: Also, you have an event handler inside an event handler, which never works out well.

Comment: the div #created is actually a bootstrap modal's internal body div. What i am doing is pasting results into that div and then loading it show previews.

Comment: You can use `preventDefault()` method to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code for submitPreview button click does not look correct to me ( *on the click handler, you are basically registering the submit event code!*). Try changing to this clean version. Also, make sure to wrap your event handler code inside the `document.ready` event to avoid other issues.

Also you need to read the `method` attribute  of the form, not `GET` attribute.

```
$(function(){

   $('#submitpreview').click(function(e) {

      e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default form submit behaviour
      var _this=$(this).closest("form");

      $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...

        data:_this.serialize(), // get the form data
        type: _this.attr('method'), // GET or POST
        url: 'test.php', // the file to call
        success: function(response) { // on success..
           $('#created').html(response); // update the DIV    
        }

      });
  });

});
```

Since your form action value is set to `dopdf.php`, when user clicks that button, It will be submitted to `dopdf.php`. You do not need any additional jQuery click handler for that.

Comment: Thank you, It fixed my issue.

Answer (score 0):

you could do the following

- your script like this

  ```
  $('#form').submit(function() {
       $.ajax({ // create an AJAX call...

          data: $(this).serialize(), // get the form data
          type: $(this).attr('GET'), // GET or POST
          url: 'test.php', // the file to call
          success: function(response) { // on success..
              $('#created').html(response); // update the DIV

          }
      });
  });
  ```

and the form as it is. don't change  it